# How can we get complete url from the short url

Tags: ios, hyperlink

I have [sharable here](https://j.map.baidu.com/YwUSO) from Baidu maps, I want to get that complete URL with the short URL string. How can we do that? 
For example, if I open same link 'https://j.map.baidu.com/YwUSO' in the browser after reloading I am getting a complete link like this *https://map.baidu.com/?shareurl=1&poiShareUid=ecdb75e513cf93e16fa3ccc0*

So, I want to do the same in IOS app, I should get complete URL in the app, How can we achieve that.

Comment: You can get it in `func webView(WKWebView, didFinish: WKNavigation!)
 ` of WKWebKit's NavigationDelegate

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, perform the request and retrieve the `URL` of the `URLResponse`

```
let urlStr = "https://j.map.baidu.com/YwUSO"
let url = URL(string: "https://j.map.baidu.com/YwUSO")!

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
    let expandedURL = urlResponse?.url?.absoluteString
    print("expandedURL GET: \(expandedURL ?? "Oops, not URL")")
}.resume()
```

What can also be done and should be a little more optimized is doing a "HEAD" request (which won't download the content contrary to "GET"), but you need then to use a `URLRequest` and not only a `URL` and specify its `httpMethod` to "HEAD".

```
let urlStr = "https://j.map.baidu.com/YwUSO"
let url = URL(string: "https://j.map.baidu.com/YwUSO")!
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
urlRequest.httpMethod = "HEAD"

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
    let expandedURL = urlResponse?.url?.absoluteString
    print("expandedURL HEAD: \(expandedURL ?? "Oops, not URL")")
}.resume()
```

Note I unwrapped badly (using "!") for the purpose of the test.

Comment: Thanks, Its working :)

Answer (score 0):

For iOS app I hope you are using UIWebView to load the URLs. Your class should conform to UIWebViewDelegate. Then use the below code to extract the redirected URL

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request mainDocumentURL];
    NSLog(@"The Redirected URL is: %@", url);
    // Return YES if you want to load the page, and NO if you don't.
    return NO;
}
```