# Converting a short URL to a full url in swift 5

Tags: xcode, swift5

Hello I'm trying to convert a short URL like https://goo.gl/maps/MoaZNS825rpixfKu5 to its original URL https://www.google.com/maps/place/WhirlyBall+Twin+Cities/@44.8508658,-93.2389179,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x87f62f7bd688277b:0xc0ec9f7b1ccd0da8!8m2!3d44.8510743!4d-93.2366811?hl=en-US

I found some solutions in similar old posts but they are not working with Xcode 12.4

I tried using the below code but it didn't return any value when I try to print expandedURL

```
let shortURL = "https://goo.gl/maps/MoaZNS825rpixfKu5"
func performRequest(urlString: String){

let urlString = shortURL
let url = URL(string: urlString)!
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
urlRequest.httpMethod = "HEAD"

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
    let expandedURL = urlResponse?.url?.absoluteString
    print("expandedURL HEAD: \(expandedURL ?? "Oops, not URL")")
}

.resume()
}
```

Comment: "I found some solutions in similar old posts but they are not working with Xcode 12.4" How so? A HEAD request seems to work (quickly tested): See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49647732/1801544 ?

Comment: "not working with Xcode 12.4". Not working how?

Comment: I updated the question with the code I'm trying to use

Comment: I got it work in Playground. How do you test it? You know that the `dataTask((with:handler:)` is asynchrone, right?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work with the below code
I know it's somehow a primitive way but it just worked with me :)

```
let shortURL = //"https://goo.gl/maps/MoaZNS825rpixfKu5"
"https://goo.gl/maps/xNdKp1Q1KqFeWQv99"

performRequest (urlString: shortURL)

func performRequest(urlString: String){

if let url = URL(string: urlString){
let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "HEAD"
let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: handle(data:response:error:))

task.resume()
}
}


func handle (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?){
if error != nil {
    print (error)
    return 
}
if let safeData = data {
    let dataString = String(data: safeData, encoding: .utf8)
    let expandedURL = response?.url?.absoluteString
    print(expandedURL!)
}
}
```

Comment: It's unclear, you don't use `safeData` nor `dataString`. So you check only of `response?.url?.absoluteString` which is what was already doing the initial code...